# How can I use the navbar toggler with a Bootstrap dashboard?

Tags: javascript, html, bootstrap-4, navigation

I am trying to create an Admin Panel, using the Bootstrap Material Dashboard from Creative Tim.

I've set everything up, however when trying to use it on a smaller screen, the navbar toggler does not work, thus you cannot navigate the page. I've inlcluded the navbar code below, any help is appreciated.

```
      <nav class="navbar navbar-expand-lg navbar-transparent navbar-absolute fixed-top">
        <div class="container-fluid">
          <div class="navbar-wrapper">
            <a class="navbar-brand" href="javascript:;">Dashboard - <?=$_SESSION['name']?></a>
          </div>
          <button class="navbar-toggler collapsed" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" aria-controls="navigation-index" aria-expanded="false" aria-label="Toggle navigation" data-target="#mobileNav">
            <span class="navbar-toggler-icon icon-bar"></span>
            <span class="navbar-toggler-icon icon-bar"></span>
            <span class="navbar-toggler-icon icon-bar"></span>
          </button>
          <div class="collapse navbar-collapse justify-content-end">
                        <button type="button" class="btn btn-default">
                            <a href="./logout.php">
                                Log out
                            </a>
                        </button>
            <ul class="navbar-nav">
              <!-- your navbar here -->
            </ul>
          </div>
        </div>
      </nav>
```

Answer (score 0):

Replace this:

```
<button class="navbar-toggler collapsed" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" aria-controls="navigation-index" aria-expanded="false" aria-label="Toggle navigation" data-target="#mobileNav">
```

With this:

```
<button class="navbar-toggler" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" aria-controls="navigation-index" aria-expanded="false" aria-label="Toggle navigation">
```

Comment: My best advice would be to go over the code again. Since we do not have your full code we cannot guess what is going on here. Could be multiple things or just one thing. 
Try and download the original file again and compare with yours to figure out what goes wrong.